# How to un-flatten data in VBA

Tags: excel, vba, xls, xlsx

I am new to VBA and tried to find help on Google without success, Moreover, I don't have knowledge what to search for below problem.

Below is an example of my worksheet which is required to un-flatten and it contains more than 2500 rows

```
  A   |   B    | C |   D
Text1 | Dummy1 | 1 | Power1
Text1 | Dummy1 | 1 | Power2
Text1 | Dummy2 | 1 | Power1
Text3 | Dummy3 | 1 | Power1
Text3 | Dummy3 | 1 | Power2
```

I am looking for the solution in VBA to get the result in below format

```
  A   |   B    | C |       D
Text1 | Dummy1 | 2 | Power1 Power2
Text1 | Dummy2 | 1 | Power1
Text3 | Dummy3 | 2 | Power1 Power2
```

If (A1,B1) is equal to (A2,B2), then count 1+1 and replace contents of D1 cell with D1+D2 (POWER1 and POWER2 (new line in same cell))

I am wondering if anyone knows how to do this or what it's called?

Thank you!

Comment: you could try a pivot table and drop columns A,B into the row headers and D into the column header, and C as the main table field (forget what it is called).

Comment: It's called *pivoting*, but AFAIK you can't achieve column D concatenation with a pivot. So if your "desired result" *has* to look *exactly* like that, your only hope is with VBA code that iterates the data and moves it around. But before you ask this community about a problem, you have to *encounter* a **specific** *programming* problem, and show us where you're stumped and what you've tried. "Here's what I need, can anyone code this for me?" is off-topic here. Please see [ask].

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are lucky, because I am bored... this way I will throw you some lines of code which will do what you desire. But as a downside (like a small punishment for not showing code), I made it slow and hard to read :P

```
Sub test()
  Dim a(2) As Range
  Set a(0) = ActiveSheet.Range("A2:D2")
  While a(0)(1).Value <> ""
    Set a(1) = a(0).Offset(1)
    Set a(2) = Nothing
    While a(1)(1).Value <> ""
      If a(0)(1).Value = a(1)(1).Value And a(0)(2).Value = a(1)(2).Value Then
        a(0)(3).Value = a(0)(3).Value + a(1)(3).Value
        a(0)(4).Value = a(0)(4).Value & " " & a(1)(4).Value
        If a(2) Is Nothing Then
          Set a(2) = a(1)
        Else
          Set a(2) = Union(a(2), a(1))
        End If
      End If
      Set a(1) = a(1).Offset(1)
    Wend
    If Not a(2) Is Nothing Then a(2).EntireRow.Delete xlUp
    Set a(0) = a(0).Offset(1)
  Wend
End Sub
```

Still, feel free to ask if any questions pop up ;)

Comment: Thank you very much, solution is perfect. You have saved my life :)